# Ubuntu reboot computer instead of shutdown

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

So I found that a normal issue is that while using the shutdown command on Ubuntu, it restarts. Well I am trying to get said behavior so that when the shutdown command is issued (Without adding the reboot flag), or in the GUI the shutdown is pressed, the computer reboots. The only way to turn the computer would be using the physical shutdown button.
I have tried setting up a service on shutdown and running the `reboot` command but it did not work.
Is there anyway to archive said behaviour?

Comment: Do you have a dual booted system or Windows installed alongside?

Comment: Nope, it a VM running Ubuntu which I want to always be on

Comment: Is the result the same when using poweroff ?